# How do i iterate through a list having dictionaries in it,ietration must be done on the values of one key

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to go through all 'filenames' keys to read it. For example i want to read '20220214T132301560.jpg' like this all jpg files in it.
how shall i do that?

```
list=[{'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:01.560000',
  'filename': '20220214T132301560.jpg'},
 {'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:03.840000',
  'filename': '20220214T132303840.jpg'},
 {'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:07.860000',
  'filename': '20220214T132307860.jpg'}]
```

Comment: Iterating over a list of dictionaries is fairly simple, you just need access to your key-value pair for each dictionary in the list. What have you tried?

Comment: Additionally, it's poor form to name a list `list` as it is a reserved name. If you MUST name it "list", lead with an underscore, i.e. `_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access all of the `filename` values:

```
_list = [
    {'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:01.560000', 'filename': '20220214T132301560.jpg'},
    {'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:03.840000', 'filename': '20220214T132303840.jpg'},
    {'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:07.860000', 'filename': '20220214T132307860.jpg'}
]

jpegs = [d['filename'] for d in _list]
print(jpegs)
```

```
['20220214T132303840.jpg', '20220214T132303840.jpg', '20220214T132307860.jpg']
```

Comment: I am sorry if my question was misinterpreted to you. Actually my question is to retrieve all those jpg images present in all dictionaries of that _list. Nothing else I need from that _list. how shall i do that?

Comment: This code accomplishes what you want to do.

Comment: I suggest you post your code. I get your expected output with the code above. You haven't posted any code, so we don't know what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the dict entry in your list if it's filename matches your desired value:

```
def foo(target):
    _list=[{'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:01.560000',
      'filename': '20220214T132301560.jpg'},
     {'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:03.840000',
      'filename': '20220214T132303840.jpg'},
     {'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:07.860000',
      'filename': '20220214T132307860.jpg'}]

    for d in _list:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if v == target:
                return d

print(foo("20220214T132301560.jpg"))
```

**RESULT:**
{'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:01.560000', 'filename': '20220214T132301560.jpg'}

Notes: Do not use `list` as a variable name. It is a type name, reserved in Python.

Comment: noted on  _list  to be used as a variable name.

Comment: I am sorry if my question was misinterpreted to you. Actually my question is to retrieve all those jpg images present in all dictionaries of _list. Nothing else I need from that _list. how shall i do that?